# Calendar HTML CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I have created a calendar using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
I wanted it to be as a event booking calendar (will be a separate link on desired days that takes the users to a page that deals with the bookings)
Based on the condition of year, month and date, I want to add another tag i.e. anchor tag,  on desired days with a link and users could click on that link available on the respective day on the calendar.
But I have not been able to add separate anchor tag from the JavaScript based on the condition of the year, month and day. Can some one help me to do it please.
I have attached my html, css and JavaScript code here.
Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="calendar">
        <div class="month">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
          <div class="date">
            <h1 class="month_particular"></h1>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="weekdays">
          <div>Sun</div>
          <div>Mon</div>
          <div>Tue</div>
          <div>Wed</div>
          <div>Thu</div>
          <div>Fri</div>
          <div>Sat</div>
        </div>
        <div class="days">
          <a href="google.com">hy babe</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #12121f;
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calendar {
  width: 45rem;
  height: 52rem;
  background-color: #460c28;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.month {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12rem;
  background-color: #914d12;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.month i {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.month h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.month p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.weekdays {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.weekdays div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  width: calc(44.2rem / 7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.days {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.days div {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  width: calc(40.2rem / 7);
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.days div:hover:not(.today) {
  background-color: #636713;
  border: 0.2rem solid #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-date,
.next-date {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.today {
  background-color: #636713;
}
```

And My JS code is

```
    const date = new Date();
const saal = date.getFullYear();
const maina = document.querySelector(".month_particular");
const deen = document.querySelector(".days");
const link = document.querySelector(".link");

const renderCalendar = () => {
  date.setDate(1);

  const monthDays = document.querySelector(".days");

  const lastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDate();

  const prevLastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    0
  ).getDate();

  const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();

  const lastDayIndex = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDay();

  const nextDays = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;

  const months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  document.querySelector(".date h1").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];

  document.querySelector(".date p").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();

  let days = "";

  for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--) {
    days += `<div class="prev-date">${prevLastDay - x + 1}</div>`;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
    if (
      i === new Date().getDate() &&
      date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()
    ) {
      days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
    } else {
      days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
    }
  }

  for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
    days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
  }
  monthDays.innerHTML = days;
  if (maina === "APRIL" && deen == 4) {
    deen.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", '<a href="google.com">hey baby</a>');
  }
};

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

renderCalendar();
console.log(saal);
console.log(maina);
console.log(deen);
```